# How can I set infinity session time out in an ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-config

I'm working on an ASP.NET project. How can I increase the session timeout? (infinity timeout)

Or should I do this on IIS? If it is possible, please explain.

Comment: set a session cookie with far future expire date.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set `session timeout` in `web.config` as shown below. The value is showing minutes, so you can set as long as you want, up until a year.

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
         <sessionState timeout="200"></sessionState>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

> The Timeout property can be set in the Web.config file for an
>   application using the timeout attribute of the sessionState
>   configuration element, or you can set the Timeout property value
>   directly using application code.
>
> The Timeout property cannot be set to a value greater than 525,600
>   minutes (1 year). The default value is 20 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.. 
If you know please explain.. How can I do same  on IIS

Comment: You write in your web.config file, it will automatic configure your IIS because web.config is Configuration file for application..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign it to unlimited. You can increase the value in minutes using the time out attribute of Session state element in web.config

```
<sessionState timeout="30">
</sessionState>
```

By default session timeout value is 20 minutes. Also in your case if you are using forms authentication, check the authentication time out value as well

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx"  protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is by setting the timeout in web.config file. Like

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

The other way is by setting the time-out in server side code in .cs file. Like

```
Session.Timeout = 100;
```

The time-out value entered will be read as minutes. If set to 0, then there will be an error page displaying session time-out value cannot be 0 and must be >0.