# Asp.net and SignalR client freezes

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have monitoring web application that runs constantly.
The server is Asp.net and it sends notifications to the clients with SignalR.
The problem is that after X period of time the client freezes and refresh must be performed.
I tried with setInterval to check the SignalR hub connection state `$.connection.hub.state !== $.signalR.connectionState.connected` and then reconnect but it didn't help.

Comment: This may be caused by IIS Session Timeout. I can't guarantee it helps, but look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239448/how-can-i-set-infinity-session-time-out-in-asp-net-project

Comment: Thanks I'll try it. but the strange thing is that I didn't have any timeout configured and I read that default timeout is 20 minutes, but it takes much more time to freeze.